# Office Communicator icon above Lync icon

Tags: presence-indication

We have a strange issue where some users with Lync installed get the old MOC icon above the Lync icon. According to them they have never had MOC intalled on their computers. Could it be some registry thing or some IE plugin? Other users don't have the issue even though they have the same version of Lync. The icon is the one below:

[image]

/Niclas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer loaded the name.dll add-on from an old Office 2007 installation instead from the Office 2010 folder.

Answer (score 1):

For that to appear it obviously means that MOC was installed at some point, even if they never used it.  Go to one of the affected machines and open Internet Explorer and choose Manage Addons.  That will list all of the addons that IE is loading and it will likely appear there.

To fix this you can either band-aid it in IE by disabling the older addon or fix it the right way by uninstalling the old Communicator via Control Panel - Programs - Uninstall.

Comment: Actually we managed to solve this. It seems like they had Office 2007 installed before and then installed Office 2010. Unfortunately Internet Explorer still loaded the name.dll from the Office 2007 folder instead of the new Office 2010.